# xsl trigger drop down with onchange using a custom attribute

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010, onchange, html.dropdownlistfor

I am creating a drop down using xsl for a dynamic list in SharePoint 2010.

I am trying to trigger the value of a custom attribute instead of the value attribute.
Ideally if i was not using a drop down i would have the a tag with href = # and then "data-reveal-id" would trigger my popup box.

```
<a href="#" class="thedistributor" data-reveal-id="{@Location}">
<xsl:value-of select="@Title"/> </a>
```

However when using the drop down I am using  so I cannot figure out how to trigger the "data-reveal-id" Any suggestions?

```
<select name="distributors" id="distributors" class="dropdown-select" onChange="window.location.href=this.value">
<option value="#" data-reveal-id="{@Location}">
<xsl:value-of select="@Title"/> 
    </option>
```